# MacOs VoiceOver does not read websites in firefox?

Tags: firefox, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

MacOs 10.14.5 VoiceOver does not recognize websites in Firefox. Try any website including [Mozilla's own site](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/) and use MacOS VoiceOver. The content is not read by the screen reader at all. VoiceOver will only read the Firefox application window and nothing within it. VoiceOver is listed as available for Firefox https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/accessibility-features-firefox-make-firefox-and-we but not a single site is readable by VoiceOver.

Comment: it is a well known issue, VoiceOver isn't listed anywhere on that page, you may have read the 'list of common screen readers'. VoiceOver is never very good with FireFox, use Google Chrome or Safari. You should get some output but it is not recommended. Firefox + NVDA however works beautifully.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I have also had good success with Jaws + Firefox. But yes, NVDA is definitely the best combination.